# CSS displaying elements vertically down instead of hortizontal straight

Tags: html, css

I have elements which are wrapped inside a div . The elements are displayed in a horizontal direction inside the div.
The problem is , I can't figure out how to display the elements vertically down direction.
I done some research and one solution was to use vertical-align but it doesn't seem to work.

Here an example of what I"m trying to accomplish

http://s9.postimg.org/6i34jzazz/save.jpg

My CSS

```
  .container {height:500px; width: 700px; background-color:#00B358}
```

My HTML

```
  <html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navigation.css">
  </head>

  <div class="container ">
  <img border="0" src="download.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228">
  <img border="0" src="1.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228">
  <img border="0" src="2.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228">
  </div>
```

Comment: so you want them 1,3 then next row 2,4 and repeted?

Comment: @Class Yep , In vertically down then up

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to achieve what you are trying to do without re-organizing your markup. You will likely have to put your divs in column containers (at least until flexbox is widely used!).

#### Quick Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-1">
        <img border="0" src="download.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock">
        <img border="0" src="1.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <img border="0" src="1.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    display: block;
}

.container > div {
    float: left;
}
```

#### Explaination:

The natural flow, if elements are inline, is to appear beside one another until a line break is needed. If elements are block level they will always appear below the former element. The other option is to float the elements, but again it will appear beside the former element if there is room, not below.

That's why you would have to adjust your markup to group the elements that you want in a vertical line together--then float the next group beside it.

Comment: Could you give me an example . I"m bit confused

Comment: dsundy , It still display in a horizontal way

Comment: The inline widths and heights are messing it up. I'll edit my answer to fix. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsundy/ZPWR2/) to show you how it works.

Comment: dsundy your jsFiddle URL leads to the homepage

Comment: I see , you have to place them in columns in order to make it work

Comment: Is their a way to limit it so If it reached bottom , go next coloumn? instead of placing pictures in different coloumn

Comment: Your answer works but I want to set a boundary limited . So when a picture reaches the end of the height . GO next coloumn

Comment: Unfortunately that can't be done without javascript. This is a jQuery plugin that flows column content: [Coumnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin) good luck!

Comment: dsunday thank you very much for your help . I appreciate every second of your help :D

Comment: Instead `display: block:` you probably intended `display: block;` with semicolon instead of colon, I presume.

Comment: @BernhardBodenstorfer Definitely. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the images within your div to display:block; not sure if this below is the correct format for "element type" within "class", but it should point you in the right direction.

This will put the images one under the other.

.box1 img {display:block;}

Comment: I tried yourr answer but what it does is enlarge the images to the size of the container

Comment: display:block; should put them all one under the other... see here: http://dustwell.com/div-span-inline-block.html

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found `column-count` which works if you have a modern browser

```
-moz-column-count
-webkit-column-count
column-count
```

you might want to fiddle with the `column-count`, but it should work for your purpose, as well you might want to mess with `column-width` to achieve the desired outcome you want.

```
-moz-column-width
-webkit-column-width
column-width
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Class/7spZT/)

[browsers that support column-count](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns/#t02)

[A List Apart: Multi-Column](http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists)

you might have to implement a js/html conditional check for older browsers to create the same effect