# CSS Display in-line block vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: css

I have a list items similar to the one below using display in-lineblock

[List of Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4kkH.png)

Is there a way in which i can have the list of items display in this way instead.

[List of Blocks listed downwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVng7.png)

I've tried doing the code below which i found in this question [CSS displaying elements vertically down instead of hortizontal straight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825118/css-displaying-elements-vertically-down-instead-of-hortizontal-straight)
However my items just carried on in a list outside of the div rather than going in the list style i want

```
img {
display: block:}

.container > div {
float: left;}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You'd need to group each pair of two blocks to be placed vertically underneath each other in a container.

Comment: Use flexbox for this...is the best way to acheive what you want - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution A**

one way to do is if you group your elements so that you have different cols.

```css
.group {
  display:inline-block
}
.floatbox {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box1
    </h1>
    </div>
 <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box2
    </h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box3
    </h1>
    </div>
 <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box4
    </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Solution B**

using `column-count`  see more here > [CSS3 Multiple Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

```css
.floatbox {
  border:1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;

 
}
.container {
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box1
    </h1>
    </div>
 <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box2
    </h1>
    </div>


    <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box3
    </h1>
    </div>
 <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box4
    </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Solution C**

using `flexbox` but this is a bit tricky because it makes 2 columns ( or more ) only if the height of the combined items is greater than the height of the container

in the below example , each box has height of `100px` and the `container` has height of `200px` so that's why only 2 boxes fit inside one column. it's not as responsive as the previous two solutions

```css
.floatbox {
  border:1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:100px;

 
}
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   align-items: center;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
   -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
   flex-flow: column wrap;
   -webkit-align-content: stretch;
   align-content: stretch;
   max-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box1
    </h1>
    </div>
 <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box2
    </h1>
    </div>


    <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box3
    </h1>
    </div>
 <div class ="floatbox">
    <h1>
    Floating Box4
    </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

let me know if it helps

Comment: Worked a treat, Thanks very much :)

Comment: I tried solution A, I'll give the over two solutions ago as well now